# Moving files to another non-master branch, and have both branches merged to master

Tags: git

In my working branch 'A' (non-master) I have files, the paths root/folder1/a, root/folder2/b, root/folder3/c.
I realized that these files should be part of another working branch 'B'.

1. I added these files to branch 'B', pushed to remote and merged 'B' to Master. This step was simple and went well.
2. On 'A', I need to delete the same files, rebase 'A' with latest master, push to remote and merge with master. In this sequence of steps ('2'), I messed up in the rebase with master part, leading to the final merge to master deleting the three files.

a. Is there anything particular I should've kept in mind for this sequence of steps ('2')?

b. What's a clean way to address this issue. Note that the merge to 'master' is done, and master now doesn't have the three files. One way obviously is to repeat '1' (create new branch, add files and merge to master). I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: It would help a lot to stop thinking of a branch as containing files. The whole idea that files are "in" a branch or can be "part of" a branch is a false mental picture. One needs to imagine Git tasks in terms of what Git is and does.

Comment: That said, for path based rewriting of history you're going to want something like this: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo